# Is there any MVP template for Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, mvp

like the MVC Framework provided by MS to create folder structure?

Answer (score 2):

You can use ASP.NET MVC to do MVP. Basically it's called MVVM: Model-View View-Model. Just add a ViewModel folder, add ViewModel classes, and bind your views to the ViewModels.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking the same techie...

I found this:
http://dnnmvptemplate.codeplex.com/